# "RR_4036 Error connecting to database [[Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database]

Tags: teradata, informatica-powercenter

ERROR : RR_4036 : Error connecting to database [
[Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] The parcel stream is invalid.Unable to get catalog string.[Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Unable to get catalog string.
Database driver error...
Function Name : Connect
Database driver error...
Function Name : Connect
Database Error: Failed to connect to database using user [EDW_AKRITIV_ETL] and connection string [Teradata_Prod_US].].

---

i am using informatica 9.6.1
and teradata 16.20

Comment: What's the driver version and database version? My first thought is you are using an older driver against a newer db.

Comment: i am using informatica 9.6.1
and teradata 16.20

Comment: can you try using datadirect driver? Have you setup ODBC.ini etc. in server and using correct connection string? Is server connection working and client isnt? or non working?